# All valuations equal one : unit?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $F$ be a global field with integers $o$, and let $x \in F$. Does $|x|_v =1$ for all non-archimedean valuations of $F$ imply that $x \in o^\times$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\cal O$ the (possibly fractional) ideal generated by $x$. If it is non-trivial, i.e. $\cal O\neq x\cal O$, it must be a product of (possibly some inverted) prime ideals. The valuation of $x$ at those primes is not $1$.

Thus.....

Comment: I do not understand. Do you say $|x|_v \neq 1$ does not imply $x \in o^\times$? Do you assume that $o$ is the ring of integers of $F$, not $o \neq \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What I'm saying is that an element which is a local unit at all primes must generate the trivial fractional ideal, but then it has to be a global unit.

Comment: Okay, so in short the answer is yes. Thanks.